# In Which method is used to post the audio file at facebook

Tags: android

i am doing a sample application in face book i must upload an audio file in that what method i used to upload audio file.for example if the file contains image content we use  **params.putString("method", "photos.upload");** for uploading likewise what method i use.
 thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

After a long research i got the answer, here we use **params.putString("method","links.post")** is used for upload a link for further details in 
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/links.get/